# get value of item_type in database and make it selected in options

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this in my blade:

```
<select class="form-control" id="item_type" name="item_type">
   <option value="physical-goods" <?php if ($product->item_type="physical-goods") echo 'selected=" selected"'; ?>>Physical Goods</option>
   <option value="digital-downloads" <?php if ($product->item_type="digital-downloads") echo 'selected=" selected"'; ?>>Digital Downloads</option>
   <option value="credits" <?php if ($product->item_type="credits") echo 'selected=" selected"'; ?>>Credits</option>
</select>
```

now this is what it looks like,
[image]

even though Sample Product is a Physical Good, so it should be

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Just try adding **echo "selected"** instead of echo 'selected=" selected"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double equal to instaed of single ==

```
<?php if ($product->item_type`enter code here`=="digital-downloads") echo 'selected=" selected"'; ?>

<select class="form-control" id="item_type" name="item_type">
   <option value="physical-goods" <?php if ($product->item_type=="physical-goods") echo 'selected=" selected"'; ?>>Physical Goods</option>
   <option value="digital-downloads" <?php if ($product->item_type=="digital-downloads") echo 'selected=" selected"'; ?>>Digital Downloads</option>
   <option value="credits" <?php if ($product->item_type=="credits") echo 'selected=" selected"'; ?>>Credits</option>
</select>
```

Comment: it worked! Thank you. I will accept your answer after 5 minutes!